# js file doesn't change view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am following as my select tag which triggers the ajax call:

```
  = select('project', 'sort', sort_type, {prompt: 'Select method'})
  #sorted{ style: 'display: none' }
  #normal
    = render 'projects_list'
```

my javascript, where #project_sort is id of select tag:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#project_sort").change(function() {
    var state = $('select#project_sort :selected').val();
    jQuery.getJSON('/inspire/' + state+ '.js');
  });
})
```

my routes:

```
get '/inspire/:sort' => 'projects#index'
```

in my controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:sort] != nil
      @projects = [Project.first]
    else
      @projects = Project.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render 'populate_projects' }
    end
  end
```

populate_projects.js.haml file:

```
:plain
  $("#sorted").html("#{escape_javascript render(partial: 'projects/projects_list')}");
  $("#normal").hide();
  $("#sorted").show();
```

and _projects_list.html.haml:

```
%section.album
  %div
    - @projects.each do |project|
      %div
        %p
         # more code...
```

What should happen is when state of select tag is changed, an ajax call should be made and view must change from all projects to just the first but it doesn't. In my terminal I can see that call is made when state change, only first project is selected and populate_project.js.haml is rendered but I don't see any change in view of my broswer.

**EDIT** -
console:

```
Started GET "/inspire/stars.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-18 22:18:16 +0530
Processing by ProjectsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"sort"=>"stars"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered projects/_forked_from.html.haml (0.2ms)
  Rate Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rates".* FROM "rates"  WHERE "rates"."rateable_id" = ? AND "rates"."rateable_type" = ? AND "rates"."dimension" = 'stars' AND "rates"."rater_id" = 1  [["rateable_id", 1], ["rateable_type", "Project"]]
  RatingCache Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "rating_caches".* FROM "rating_caches"  WHERE "rating_caches"."cacheable_id" = ? AND "rating_caches"."cacheable_type" = ? AND "rating_caches"."dimension" = 'stars' LIMIT 1  [["cacheable_id", 1], ["cacheable_type", "Project"]]
  Rendered projects/_projects_list.html.haml (22.9ms)
  Rendered projects/populate_projects.js.haml (24.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 29.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Comment: use console.log to debug.i think you even need to visit other child nodes and then update html....have a check though.use firebug and fire same in console tab to check if   $("#sorted").html("testing working"); actually working.

Comment: visit other child nodes and then update html? I am sorry, I am not able to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have added my console log

Comment: i need you to use firebug in firefox to debug using console.log() for js codes...not server logs

Comment: I replaced `jQuery.getJSON('/inspire/' + state+ '.js');` with `$.get("/inspire/"+state+".js");` and it is working now. I am not sure why tho.